# Working with patient/customer data outside of the office

Tags: development-environment

**Background**
I am a developer that works for a health care organization.  We build a variety of business apps that a majority of them contain PHI (Patient Health Information).  We work on laptops in-house and occasionally have the option to work from home.  Something we are discussing though is how do we handle the data stored on our laptops when we are working out of the office.

Although we have passwords and our laptops are encrypted that still doesn't seem like enough to us to protect data.  What I mean by that is this.  We are a small five person team.  When we are working on a task we all work locally on our own databases, on our laptops.  When the change is done we commit to svn and publish to a test server.  Our concern is my local database is a copy of production sometimes so I can test against real data.  That local database could contain thousands of records of PHI.  This is obviously a major concern to us when we takes our laptops out of our building because if I have my laptop stolen, I would be putting thousands of patients health information at risk.  Not something we want to do.

**My Question**
How do developers work as a best practice in regards to patient data safety.  Or even if it was financial?  Either way, how do people work with patient/customer data locally?

Is it fair to say that sometimes you just don't have the ability to connect in to a database behind a firewall or is that just negligence?  Even if I keep the database internal I still have project code on my laptop.  Is that bad too?
•   Should I have fake data?
•   Should all data be on an internal machine that you connect to? 
•   Should I only connect in to a machine that is internal?

I can’t imagine that is what people do all the time.

We are discussing this as a team and would love to hear your feedback in regards to "how do you or anyone work as a remote developer".

Thanks

Comment: HIPAA comes to mind http://www.onlinetech.com/compliant-hosting/hipaa-compliant-hosting/resources/what-is-hipaa-compliance

Comment: Fake data comes immediately to mind for what I'd do.  Spend some time coding up a generator that can create plausible data to populate your system with.

Comment: That's what I was thinking but I wasn't sure how other people handled that situation.  Thanks for the feedback